# How can I prevent a user from accessing the directory paths of my website?

Tags: php, localhost, webserver

I have recently finished my web project. Or I should say almost.
It still runs on XAMPP, and my source is inside the htdocs folder.

If I want to access my website I simply go to:

```
http://localhost/myapp/mypath/index.php
```

How do I put this in production?
I know on a real webserver the localhost is gonna be replaced by a domain name or something.

like

```
http://mywebsite.com/myapp/mypath/index.php
```

I certainly do not want people to manipulate the path and access objects they're not supposed to.

During the course of development, I constantly asked myself, how I could do this.
Well now I'm done and I have no clue. And I am afraid that I'd have needed to take sooner action there.

Please help

Comment: Do you mean how to write the path dynamic? Did you hard coded it in your application?

Comment: I basically have separate scripts for each job. like addPerson

Comment: _"access objects they're not supposed to"_ - Like what, for example? Normally, you just keep the index file (a proxy that all calls goes through) and the static assets (images/js/css etc) under the web root and keep the rest of the application (including config files and such) outside oft he web root so they can't be accessed directly.

Comment: I wasn't finished. like addPerson.php that stores a new person to the database. and i have a structure full of folders and scripts like these

Comment: It was years I did these things from scratch, but basically you want to look into Routing. You want to deny access to all paths and only allow routes. So instead of /path/index.php it'll look like /index which may run some code and then return a html file. https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/

Comment: The question is _very_ unclear. _"how to prevent"_ is heavily dependent on your code structure, what files you want to protect, why, when, who should be able to call those files, how are they used etc. If anyone (like you) would need to access those files directly through a browser, you need to set up some kind of auth (IP check/login or similar) but if those files should never be accessed directly (if they are included in other files), then put them outside of the web root. We need way more info.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson seems like I messed up. I have for example: localhost/menu.php/ menu.php containes a html document where I include a header with all my my Javascript, jquery and bootstraps CDNs. from there the user is able to klick on a link inside a form with action="anotherScript.php" which redirects to there and shows the html structure defined in anotherScript.php. the address would then look like localhost/anotherScript.php. and if you remove everything but localhost, it would show every script and folder in my root

Comment: how do I put them outside of the web root? those are files I redirect to, files I fetch data from with ajax etc.